# Android shared preferences for the checkbox is working on emulator but not working on android phone?

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, emulation

> shared preferences is used for checkbox its works on emulator and KitKat 4.2,when I run it marshmallow checkbox state is not save.

```
final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this
final CheckBox chkUseMetricUntis = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.chkMetricUnits);
 chkUseMetricUntis .setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("checked",false));
        chkUseMetricUntis.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

> preference

```
                preferences.edit().putBoolean("checked",isChecked).apply();
                System.out.print("okkkk");
                if (chkUseMetricUntis.isChecked()) {

                    speedGps.this.updateSpeed(null);

                }
                else disableBroadcastReceiver(view);
                disableCallBroadCastReceiver(view);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your sharedpreference deafult location  or on a device location ? From Lollipop onwards user permission is required to access and write.